# Is it possible to port a WPF 3D app to UWP / UAP

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, uwp

I wrote an WPF app using all the 3D stuff of WPF which contains several Views displaying 3D data. IMHO WPF is not the platform for further development of the app so I am searching for some ways to port it to a Universal App/Windows Store App/UWP.
The way, Microsoft is promoting, is to use Unity meaning a complete redevelopment and complicated workflows because it should be a 2D-App with some 3D views.
The other way I was looking at way using [Helix-Toolkit](https://github.com/helix-toolkit), because it does not just offer the WPF-way of displaying 3D but also the DirectX way using SharpDX. Unfortunately the progress concerning UWP is pretty low and not currently usable in the extend I need (like displaying custom geometries etc.).
Is anybody out there who got the same problem and found a workaround?
TY!

Comment: have you tried the desktop bridge - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop

Answer (score 1):

You may also like to consider Monogame. Like Helix-Toolkit it's based on SharpDX (when it's on Windows anyway). It's not quite as "componentised" as Helix-Toolkit but it's possible to make your app UWP-first and Monogame-second.